# Cannot set gas price price to zero in Hardhat tests

Tags: solidity, hardhat, gas-price

I am trying to test a contract using Hardhat and want to set the gas price to zero. This will make it easier to see if my functions are working correctly, in that I can easily calculate the correct answer to many digits absent gas costs, while adjusting for gas on each transaction is a major pain. I tried to set the gas price to zero in `hardhat.config.js`, but when I ran `npx hardhat test` it gave me the error

```
InvalidInputError: Transaction gasPrice (0) is too low for the next block, which has a baseFeePerGas of 875000000
```

Is there a way to set the gas price to zero in Hardhat? I am using hardhat 2.14.0.

Comment: Hardhat replicate how the real chain works and there is no way to send a tx with zero gas because that means you are not sending enough eth to do anything, you could try doing a static call instead

Answer (score 1):

If you just have `gasPrice: 0` in the config file, it won't work, but I just discovered that if additionally, you set `initialBaseFeePerGas: 0`, it works.